# How to go about making an upside-down PopupMenu

Tags: android, android-widget, popupmenu, rotatetransform

I am coding an Android game in which 2 players play at the same time. Player 1 faces the phone in a normal way and Player 2 faces it upside down. Each player can change preferences which I want to be accessed through a popup menu which will be anchored to an onscreen Button. Each player will have their own Button.

I have managed to rotate the widgets for Player 2 by adding the following xml tags in the layout resources:

```
android:rotation="180"
```

So that part is all well.

My question is, how do I go about making an `android.widget.PopupMenu` also appear upside down for Player 2? The effect I am looking for is that Player 2 will get a `PopupMenu` which they would be able to read from their angle.

Any help or suggestions on how to best achieve this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar issue by using `PopupWindow`.  `PopupWindow` can be constructed with any layout of your choosing, such as one you inflate from xml.  That layout can have the `android:rotation` tags.

In my case I used

> new PopupWindow(popupContent, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

where `popupContent` is the layout I inflated from xml.

PopupWindow docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html